# If $a,b,c,a^2+b^2+c^2$ are primes, then $a$ or $b$ or $c$ is equal to $3$

Tags: prime-numbers, diophantine-equations, conjectures

Given primes $a,b,c$ such that $a^2+b^2+c^2$ is prime, then $3\in\{a,b,c\}$.

Tested for $a,b,c<500$.

Comment: This time a clue to a solution would have come from looking at factorizations of $a^2+b^2+c^2$ whenever $a,b,c$ are primes $\neq3$. You would have quickly noticed that all those sums of squares share $3$ as a factor. I don't know how much experience helps here. I bring this up because the next time you make this kind of a discovery (thanks for sharing them!), you may be able to see the way to an answer yourself. With your programming skills it would probably be easy to reach that point with a suitably tailored version of your program. It's not unlike debugging IMHO.

Comment: I think it's a question of lack self confidence and experience. I can't tell if there is an easy trick or not. I never took a course in arithmetic, but is never the less fascinated by the primes and can't stop looking for relations. I'll think about the debugging thinking.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If $p\neq3$, $p$ a prime, then $p^2\equiv1\pmod3$. So if $3\notin\{a,b,c\}$ then $3\mid a^2+b^2+c^2$.

Comment: Are there any other  prime $p$ which gives $q^2\equiv k\; (\text{mod }p)$ for any prime $q$ and the same $k$?

Comment: @Raffaele: No. By Dirichlet's theorem there are infinitely many primes $q$ such that $q\equiv a\pmod p$ <edit> **for every** $a$ **coprime to** $p$</edit>. Therefore all the quadratic residues modulo $p$ will occur as residues $k$ modulo $p$. Here $p=3$ is special because there is only a single non-zero quadratic residue modulo $3$.

Comment: Another similar result would be that if for some primes $p_i, i=1,2,3,4,5,$ we have that if $$p_1^4+p_2^4+p_3^4+p_4^4+p_5^4$$ is also a prime, then $5$ must be among those primes. This is because by Little Fermat $p_i^4\equiv1\pmod5$ unless $p_i=5$. Generalizations are hopefully easy to see (but become progressively more difficult to verify by computer for a range of primes).

Answer (score 1):

If $p\ge 5 $ is a prime then it is always of the form $6n\pm 1 ~, n \ge 1$.

Let $a,b,c$ be primes $\ge 5$. Then we've ;

$$(6n_1\pm 1)^2+(6n_2 \pm 1)^2+(6n_2 \pm 1)^2 =  \text{prime}$$

$$36(n_1^2+n_2^2+n_3^2)+12(\pm n_1\pm n_2 \pm n_3)+3 =\text{prime}$$

But in the above equation, LHS is clearly divisible by $3$ and hence not a prime. Therefore our assumption was false. Atleast one of $a,b,c$ is equal to $3$. Also, any of $a,b$ and $c$ can not be $2$ because that will lead the sum $a^2+b^2+c^2$ to be even.

Comment: Note that you also need to exclude $2$ which is not of the form $6n\pm 1$ and is less than $5$. This is trivial, of course, but shouldn't be forgotten.